# Laravel Database connection issue

Tags: php, laravel, database, postgresql, sybase

My Laraval application is working with the env file with the database Sybase and PostGre. The database connection is made successfully as well. Randomly the server is giving errors of the **Database Server Not Found** or **Invalid Username or Password** or **Authentication failed at client's place** with HTTP code 500. Once I got the error message If I tried to make the connection once again, it establishes the connection successfully. I am not able to find the root cause of this issue as my connection is started giving issues randomly. Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using a domain name or IP address for the database server? Try using an IP address.

Comment: @geldek Yes, we are already using IP address to connect with the database server.

Comment: If the problem only occurs occasionally, inspect the database connection string (connection pooling, pool size, SSL certificate configuration, caching, timeouts, keepalives...). If the connection string is not the problem, look into database and Web Server logs (I assume Apache). The issue might be the system configuration (where you hit some memory/connection/cache limit.